# Merging two dataframe by maintaining parent child relationship

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes which maintain parent child relationship. How can I merge and get the desired output as shown below.

**DF1**

```
parent child
A       A1
A       A2
```

**Df2**

```
child  data
A1      d1
A2      d2
```

**Output**->  `[{'hierarchy':['A','A1'],'data':d1},{'hierarchy':['A','A2'],'data':d2}]`

Comment: Have you try merge ?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='child', how='left')` ...